# How do the ending narrations in DE:HR change depending on your playstyle?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

After finishing Human Revolution and watching all the endings, I noticed that in each one the narrator mentioned "trying to follow morals" or something similar, which sounded to me like a reflection of my playing style.

I've since read elsewhere that the ending narrations do indeed change based on what happened during the game, although I have found no mention of (a) what causes the changes, and (b) what the different possible narrations are.

So...

- What can cause you to receive different narrations over the endings?
- What are the different narrations, or where can I find a transcript?

Comment: Do you have a source for the "different choices -> different narrations"?

Comment: Nothing more concrete than someone saying it in a forum... I'll have a look when I get a chance. I'd also accept a "no, this definitely  isn't true" for an answer if that's the case.

Comment: http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/forums/showthread.php?1219-Human-Revolution-Ending%28s%29-and-story-%28Big-spoilers-duh%29&p=32046&viewfull=1#post32046  -  just a random dude on the internet so far.

Comment: http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/forums/showthread.php?1219-Human-Revolution-Ending(s)-and-story-(Big-spoilers-duh)&p=35685&viewfull=1#post35685  -  secondhand quote from the voice actor.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHvTI9l5Xj0 - transcripts! So that just leaves... what exactly decides which?

Comment: Oh, wow. Suddenly the game has less of a "Ending-o-matic 5000" feel to it.

Comment: +1 I was a bit disappointed in the 4 endings I saw - looking forward to watching this vid to see how different the others are!

Comment: Spoiler: not very :p

Answer (score 6):

My sources say there are 12 possible ends for the game.

There are the 4 types of ending but the dialogue changes depending on how you played (good, neutral or evil).

This vid has the good and evil versions of the endings:

The neutral ones are out there too...

Comment: [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHvTI9l5Xj0) video includes all of them (it's linked in that video you have posted).